# How to create an instance in Python using another thread (QRunnable)

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I am trying to create a new instance of the class Execute from another thread:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.threadpool = QtCore.QThreadPool()

    def start(self, var1):
        self.threadpool.start(WorkingThread(Execute(var1)))


class Execute:
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = self.do_something(var1)

        print(self.var1)

        del self

    def __del__(self):
        print('deleted')

    def do_something(self, var1):
        for i in range(6):
            var1 += i

        return var1


class WorkingThread(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkingThread, self).__init__()
        self.fn = fn
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self):
        print('Tread_start')
        self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        print('Thread_stop')


main = Main()
main.start(5)
```

When I run the code it prints

```
20
Tread_start
```

and then crashes. I already tried to write another function which will create the instance and execute this function in a new thread:

```
def start(self, var1):
    self.threadpool.start(WorkingThread(self.start_execute(var1)))

def start_execute(self, var1):
    Execute(var1)
```

But this will result also in a crash.

So is there a way to create a new instance in a new thread? I think I understand the problem, that as soon the variable

```
self.fn = fn
```

in the class WorkingThread is defined, it creates already the instance (let me know if I am wrong pls) but I do not know how to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I already found the solution...

```
def start(self, var1):
    self.threadpool.start(WorkingThread(lambda: Execute(var1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `__call__`, to make the class callable after instantiation:

```
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.threadpool = QtCore.QThreadPool()

    def start(self, var1):
        self.threadpool.start(WorkingThread(Execute(var1)))


class Execute:
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1

    def __call__(self):
        self.do_something(self.var1)
        print(self.var1)
        del self

    def __del__(self):
        print('deleted')

    def do_something(self, var1):
        for i in range(6):
            var1 += i
        return var1
```

Out:

```
Tread_start
5
Thread_stop
deleted
```